# How to join two tables i

Tags: mysql

i want to join two tables completely

```
productbill
BillID | TransactionID 
1      |  12344
2      |  34353

viewproduct
sno|BillID|Productname|Rate|Quantity|Amount
1  |1     |xyz        |12  |2       |24

required output
  BillID|TransactionID|Productname|Rate|Quantity|Amount
    1   | 12344       |xyz        |12  |2       |24
```

my query is:

```
$joinview=mysql_query("select viewproduct.BillID,productbill.TransactionID,viewproduct.Productname,viewproduct.Rate,viewproduct.Quantity,viewproduct.Amount from viewproduct FULL OUTER JOIN  productbill ON productbill.BillID=viewproduct.BillID");
```

please help me over this

Answer (score 0):

SQL inner join is what you need !

[SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

See the sample code and demo database.

```
SELECT productbill.BillID, productbill.TransactionID, viewproduct.Productname, viewproduct.Rate, viewproduct.Quantity, viewproduct.Amount
FROM productbill
INNER JOIN viewproduct ON productbill.BillID = viewproduct.BillID;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Maasoud suggested,you need Inner Join.

Query would be

`$joinview=mysql_query("SELECT productbill.billId as billId, productbill.TransactionID as TransactionID ,viewproduct.Productname as Productname, viewproduct.Rate as Rate, viewproduct.Quantity as Quantity, viewproduct.Amount as Amount FROM productbill AS productbill  INNER JOIN viewproduct as viewproduct ON viewproduct.BillID = productbill.BillID");`